# Type assertion of a non-exported type

Tags: go, types

I am using a 3rd party package, which allows you to create structures of a certain non-exported type through an exported function.

```golang
package squirrel

type expr struct {
    sql string
    args []interface{}
}

func Expr(sql string, args ...interface{}) expr {
    return expr{sql: sql, args: args}
}
```

Because of the way some other function of this library accepts data, I ended up with such a map:

```golang
m := map[string]interface{} {
    "col1": 123,
    "col2": "a_string",
    "col3": Expr("now()"),
}
```

but because of a different function in this library I need to filter out all `squirrel.expr` from this map.

Obviously, I wasn't able to assert the type directly, by doing so:

```golang
filtered := make(map[string]interface{})
for k, v := range m {
    switch v.(type) {
    case squirrel.expr:
        continue
    default:
        filtered[k] = v
    }
}
```

Is there another way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Have you tried [reflection](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)?

Comment: @mkopriva Not yet. I'm new to the language and I have not used it so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use reflection to compare the type of values to the type of `squirrel.expr`. Type here means the [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) descriptors, acquired by [`reflect.TypeOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf).

For example:

```
m := map[string]interface{}{
    "col1": 123,
    "col2": "a_string",
    "col3": squirrel.Expr("now()"),
}
fmt.Println(m)

exprType := reflect.TypeOf(squirrel.Expr(""))

filtered := make(map[string]interface{})
for k, v := range m {
    if reflect.TypeOf(v) == exprType {
        continue
    }
    filtered[k] = v
}
fmt.Println(filtered)
```

This will output:

```
map[col1:123 col2:a_string col3:{now() []}]
map[col1:123 col2:a_string]
```

**Note:**

We obtained the `reflect.Type` descriptor of the values we want to filter out by passing the return value of a `squirrel.Expr()` call (which is of type `squirrel.expr`). This is fine in this case, but if it is unfeasible to call this function just to get the type (e.g. the call has side effects which must be avoided), we can avoid that. We can use reflection to obtain the `reflect.Type` descriptor of the `squirrel.Expr` function itself, and get the type descriptor of its return type. This is how it could be done:

```
exprType := reflect.TypeOf(squirrel.Expr).Out(0)
```

Comment: This method still requires access to the unexported type. Note that the type OP needs to compare against is `expr`, not `Expr`.

Comment: It could be done a little more ham-fistedly using `reflect.TypeOf(v).Name() == "expr"`.

Comment: @Adrian My solution doesn't refer to the unexported type, it uses the return value of the exported `squirrel.Expr()` function, which is valid. We could use reflection to "extract" the return type of `Expr()` if calling it is unfeasible, but it is not in this case. Using `Type.Name()` has more downsides than the easiness it provides.